# Missing parameter type for expanded function for reduceLeft

Tags: scala

For the following method series of transforms the `Intellij` IDE seems to "understand" what is going on: it does not note any errors/warnings and correctly shows the data types:

```
  val recsWithNames = recsWithNamesAndCnts.map(_._1)
  .reduceLeft{ case (dfCum: DataFrame,dfNew: DataFrame) => dfCum.union(dfNew)}
```

Here is the `type inference`:

[image]

However it does not compile:

```
Error:(426, 68) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: (?, org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) => ?
      val recsWithNames = recsWithNamesAndCnts.map(_._1).reduceLeft{ case (dfCum: DataFrame,dfNew: DataFrame) => dfCum.union(dfNew)}
```

This has been a bit of a pattern with `reduceLeft` so I typically end up converting to `foldLeft`. In particular the following *does* work:

```
  val dfs = recsWithNamesAndCnts.map(_._1)
  val recsWithNames = dfs.tail.foldLeft(dfs.head){ case (dfCum: DataFrame,dfNew: DataFrame) => dfCum.union(dfNew)}
```

But maybe in  this case  someone might provide some insight on the particular nuances of `reduceLeft` leading to this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduceLeft` and `foldLeft` have the following signatures:

```
def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): B

def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

Both involve an `op` that takes a `Function2`, hence both will work fine without the `case` match:

```
(dfCum: DataFrame, dfNew: DataFrame) => dfCum.union(dfNew)

// Or, shorthanded to: 

_ union _
```

On the other hand, `case (dfCum, dfNew) => dfCum.union(dfNew)` is a `Function1` (in particular, a partial function of Tuple2).  The compiler is able to interpret it and infer type `B` in `foldLeft`, but not in `reduceLeft` (my guess is due to `B >: A`).  It'll work if you help the compiler a litte:

```
reduceLeft[DataFrame]{ case (dfCum, dfNew) => dfCum.union(dfNew) }
```

Comment: v nice. I **came back** to this Q/A three months later .. and can confirm that the `[DataFrame]` hint does fix the issue.