# How to dynamically modify columns in a scala spark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe

```
val dat = Seq((1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5)).toDF("a", "b", "c")
scala> dat.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  3|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+
```

and a sequence of column names

```
val colsToModfiy = Seq("a", "b")
```

I want to multiply values by ten in the dataframe where column names match any value in my sequence.

I expect the following result:

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
| 10| 20|  3|
| 30| 40|  5|
+---+---+---+
```

My gut feeling says it should be possible using a `foldLeft()` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gut is right.

```scala
colsToModfiy.foldLeft(dat) { case (df, c) => df.withColumn(c, col(c) * 10) }.show()
```

Comment: why is `case` needed here?

Comment: Not needed ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Unfortunately with Scala I'm quite often consfused when it's needed and when not...

Comment: @Kombajn zbożowy, it comes down to the specific method's underlying signature.  See this [`SO link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322740/missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function-for-reduceleft) for a relevant discussion.

Answer (score 3):

With the `fold` approach, the number of required transformations would grow with the cols-to-modify list, as the binary operator iteratively applies changes to the dataframe.  I'd suggest going with just a `select` in this case.

```
val dat = Seq((1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5)).toDF("a", "b", "c")
val colsToModify = Seq("a", "c")
val rest = dat.columns diff colsToModify

dat.
  select(colsToModify.map(c => (col(c) * 10).as(c)) ++ rest.map(col): _*).
  show
// +---+---+---+
// |  a|  c|  b|
// +---+---+---+
// | 10| 20|  3|
// | 30| 40|  5|
// +---+---+---+
```

Or, to preserve the current column order:

```
dat.
  select(dat.columns.map( c =>
      when(lit(colsToModify.contains(c)), col(c) * 10).otherwise(col(c)).as(c)
    ): _*
  ).
  show
// +---+---+---+
// |  a|  b|  c|
// +---+---+---+
// | 10|  2| 30|
// | 30|  4| 50|
// +---+---+---+
```

Comment: It's not the fold that is the issue, writing the withColumn's out by hand will trigger the same issue.  The approach shown here ("select"ing once) is the lowest cost.

Comment: This approach changes the order of columns. If `val colsToModfiy = Seq("b", "c")`, then the select changes the order to b, c, a.

Comment: @piptoma, you're right, I've expanded the answer to address that --- although I should add that "default" column order isn't always safe to rely on, as users are expected to use explicit `select` for the wanted columns and their order.  That's true not only for Spark but RDBMS such as PostgreSQL as well.